# Unlocking button when the correct answer is filled in

Tags: javascript, html, button, local-storage

So, I am making something where the user has to fill in their username and password in the beginning and in the end they can submit their score. I want the button to be disabled when the wrong data is filled in and to enable the button when the correct data is filled in. I cant get it to work. I have the name and password stored in the localStorage.

HTML

```
<button id="submit" class="register_button" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

JavaScript

```
if (document.getElementById('name2') == localStorage.getItem('name') && document.getElementById('password2') == localStorage.getItem('password')) {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
};
```

Comment: If you need some more info, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

your expression is wrong you need to add .value after document.getElementById('name2') you are comparing the whole element not it's value

below is the working example

```
<input type="text" name="" id="name2">
<input type="text" name="" id="password2" onkeydown="validateData();">
<button id="submit" class="register_button" disabled type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>

<script>
    localStorage.setItem('name', "fazal")
    localStorage.setItem('password', "pwd")


    function validateData() {
        //alert(document.getElementById('name2').value);
        if (document.getElementById('name2').value == localStorage.getItem('name') && document.getElementById('password2').value == localStorage.getItem('password')) {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        };
    }
</script>
```